# Is there a way to determine the value of a property on a form that calls a method in a seperate class library

Tags: vb.net, winforms

Specifically aimed at winforms development.

I suspect that the answer to this is probably No but S.O.  has a nice way of introducing me to things I didn't know so I thought that I would ask anyway.

I have a class library with a number of defined methods therein. I know from personal experimentation that it is possible to get information about the application within which the class library is referenced.  What I would like to know is whether it would be possible to get information about the value of a property of a control on a form when a routine on that form calls a method in my class library without passing a specific reference to that form as a parameter of the method in the class library?

So purely as an example (because it's the only thing I can think of off the top of my head).  Is there a way that a message box (if it had been so designed to do so in the first place) could 'know' from which form a call to it had been made without that form being specifically referenced as a parameter of the message box in the first place?

Thanks for any insights you might have.

Comment: Never look for a back-door when you can simply pass the value as an argument to the method.  Also rather important that you avoid taking a dependency on the UI in a class library.  Use an event instead.

Answer (score 1):

To address the example of the MessageBox, in many of the cases you can use the active form. You can retrieve it by using [`Form.ActiveForm`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.activeform%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Of course, as regards the properties that you can request, you are limited to the properties provided by the Form or an interface that the Form implements and that the method in the other assembly also knows. To access other properties you can use Reflection, but this approach would neither be straightforward nor would it be clean.

In a more general scenario, you could provide the property value to the method as a parameter. If it is to complex to retrieve the value of the property and the value is not needed every time, you can provide a [`Func(Of TRESULT)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534960%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to the method that retrieves the value like this (sample for an integer property):

```
Public Sub DoSomethingWithAPropertyValue(propValFunc As Func(Of Integer))
    ' Do something before
    If propertyValueIsNeeded Then
        Dim propVal = propValFunc()
    End If
    ' Do something afterwards
End Sub
```

You call the method like this:

```
Public Sub SubInForm()
   Dim x As New ClassInOtherAssembly()
    x.DoSomethingWithAPropertyValue(Function() Me.IntegerProperty)
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Markus, thanks for you answer.  I hadn't considered Form.ActiveForm but given that the property that I'm really after will belong to a control attached to the active form I suspect that it would be better getting that property passed to the method directly as a parameter of the method itself rather than trying to use reflection which as you so rightly point out can get messy.

Comment: @DomSinclair: yes, Reflection should be the last resort. If you can pass the value as a parameter, this is the easiest way.

Answer (score 0):

I kind of question your intentions. There's no problem sending the information to a function or the constructor.

Instead of giving the information to the class, the class would ask for the information instead using an event.

```
Module Module1

    Sub Main()

        Dim t As New Test

        AddHandler t.GetValue, AddressOf GetValue

        t.ShowValue()
        Console.ReadLine()

    End Sub

    Public Sub GetValue(ByRef retVal As Integer)
        retVal = 123
    End Sub

End Module

Class Test

    Public Delegate Sub DelegateGetValue(ByRef retVal As Integer)
    Public Event GetValue As DelegateGetValue

    Public Sub ShowValue()

        Dim val As Integer

        RaiseEvent GetValue(val)

        Console.WriteLine(val)

    End Sub

End Class
```